# Java testing out a driver class

Tags: java, string, output, driver

I've been having some issues with this program. I have to test out using a driver class each method, but I can't seem to understand what I should do when the parameters are strings.

I had an example for `int` parameters but the example never showed anything on string parameters and how to convert. Using `null` makes my driver class run but putting an `int` or string won't.

What can I do to convert this correctly, so it can display whatever I have in the no parameter constructor?

```
public class StudentListing 
{

    private String name;
    private String number;

    public StudentListing(String n, String num)
    {
        name = n;
        number = num;
    }

    public StudentListing()
    {
        name = null;
        number = null;

    }

    public String toString()
    {
        return("Name is  " + name +
                "\nNumber is " + number + "\n");

    }

       public void show()
    {
        System.out.println(toString());
    }

    public StudentListing Clone()
    {
        StudentListing clone = new StudentListing (name, number);
        return clone;
    }

    public int compareTo(String targetKey)
    {
        return (name.compareTo(targetKey));
    }

    public void input()
    {
        name = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter a name");
        number = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter a number");
    }// end of StudentListing

}//end of class
public class StudentListingDriver 
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {

       StudentListing s1 = new StudentListing();
       StudentListing s2 = new StudentListing(null,null);
       System.out.println(s1);
       s1.input();

       StudentListing s3 = s2.clone();
       s1.show();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. You can have default values and make the no-args constructor call the other constructor.
2. Use `Integer.parseInt();` to convert from a `String` to an `Integer`.
3. You also need to check the conversion for `exception`s.

Like this:

```
public class StudentListing {
    private String name;
    private int number;

    public StudentListing(String n, int num) {
        name = n;
        number = num;
    }

    public StudentListing() {
        this("defaultName", 0);
    }

    public String toString() {
        return ("Name is  " + name + "\nNumber is " + number + "\n");
    }

    public void show() {
        System.out.println(toString());
    }

    public StudentListing Clone() {
        StudentListing clone = new StudentListing(name, number);
        return clone;
    }

    public int compareTo(String targetKey) {
        return (name.compareTo(targetKey));
    }

    public void input() {
        name = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter a name");
        number = Integer
                .parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter a number"));
    }
}
```

The tester:

```
public class StudentListingDriver {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        StudentListing s1 = new StudentListing();
        StudentListing s2 = new StudentListing(null, 0);
        System.out.println(s1);
        s1.input();
        StudentListing s3 = s2.Clone();
        s1.show();
    }
}
```